# Virtual machine environments for testing Windows software installer?

Tags: vmware, virtualization, virtualbox, hyper-v

I am developing a Windows forms application in Visual Studio under Windows 7 Ultimate and am currently building a deployment/installer package for the application.  Besides my Windows 7 development machine, I also have a Windows Server 2008 R2 server on my LAN.

It seems like having a virtual machine on which I can test my installer would be a good idea, but I have no experience using Hyper-V, VMware, or Virtual Box.

For testing the installer, would it be better to create a virtual machine on my Win 7 development PC or on the Windows 2008 R2 server?  And what virtualization software would be simplest to set up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am quite happy with VirtualBox on my PC. Free, supports snapshots ( easy to roll back to last good known state) and performance quite OK.

Comment: tigran, On your suggestion I downloaded and installed VirtualBox and was going to install a VM instance, but wondered if I should find an old XP CD to install from or download an iso from MSDN. Do you know if there is any process for cloning the installed o/s?

Comment: The easiest way is to install from CD. There are tools to convert you  physical disk to a virtual one. For example http://www.winimage.com/download.htm.